# Mount and Blade Warband: Never awarded the correct points

Tags: mount-and-blade, mount-and-blade-warband

Basically,

**When I enter a battle, it says,**

> You will get **24 renown** from this battle

However at the end of said battle **I get maybe 6-10 renown**.

**In the tournaments it say**

> 1st place, awarded **30 renown**.

However in the notifications, **I get 4-7**.

I think the tournaments has gone down now since I won so many. But even though the amount I should get has gone down, the amount I do get is always even less.

It doesnt matter where or why it assigns me it, I never get what it says I should.

Running the Floris mod if that is affecting it.

Im currently thinking of exporting my character and awarding myself another 500 renown to make up for the game. However I dont want to be cheating either, so It would have to be on morale grounds.**Is this suppose to happen or should I be getting full points?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that there is a theoretical maximum on the renown (people have reported that over 2000 renown it gets increasingly difficult). I presume that the diminishing effect of this cap is not stated in the calculations before the tournaments/battles and will be when you actually get the renown.

This probably results in the effect you are having, you get 24 renown from the battle stated, before the diminishing returns are calculated.

The formula to calculate renown works as follows:
The higher your renown, the less renown you gain for the same activities.  Any time you gain renown, the game takes your previous renown, divides it by 200, then subtracts the 
result from the renown that you just gained.

Or, as a formula:

```
Actual Renown Increase = Stated Amount - (Current/200)
```

So, in order to gain 7 when it says you gain 30, you would need to already have **7400** renown:

```
7 = 30 - (Current/200)
Current/200 = 37
Current = 7400
```

Source:
http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php/topic,115829.0.html

Comment: Actually Post #7 from your link does state a formula! You could maybe mention it. :) I have about 1600 renown. They say by 1800-2000 its very hard to increase it. There must be a mod in play as well. I found that as King i get a boost of 100 men which doesnt happen in native. So maybe this is scaled even more to counter that fact. Add it, and message me. And I will mark as answer. One way or another, diminishing renown is a normal thing. Its probably just slower for me to obtain it.

Comment: @Doomsknight added the formula to calculate renown. I'll edit it a bit to state it in a more mathmatical fashion too.

Comment: Cheers. :) Its a good answer. I spent a while trying to find this info.

Comment: @Doomsknight You are more then welcome!